# Anonymous stream in c

Tags: c, stream

Can I make an anonymous stream in c?  I don't want to create a new file on the file system, just have a stream that one function can fwrite to while the other can fread from it.  Not c++, c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe You're looking for pipes.

Forward Your STDOUT to the pipe.

Then the other application would read from the pipe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define RDR 0
#define WTR 1

char ** parseargs(char *string);

int main(void){
   char mode = 'r'; 
   char prog[50] = "/bin/ps --version";
   char **argv; 
   int p[2]; 
   pid_t pid;
   FILE *readpipe;
   int pipein, pipeout; 
   char buf; 


   /* create the pipe */
   if(pipe(p) != 0){
      fprintf(stderr, "error: could not open pipe\n");
   }

   pipein = p[RDR];
   pipeout = p[WTR];

   if((pid = fork()) == (pid_t) 0){



      close(pipein);

      dup2(pipeout, 1);
      close(pipeout);


      if(execv(argv[0], argv) == -1){
         fprintf(stderr, "error: failed to execute %s\n", argv[0]);
      }
      _exit(1);
   }

   close(pipeout);


   readpipe = fdopen(pipein, &mode);

   while(!feof(readpipe)){
      if(1 == fread(&buf, sizeof(char), 1, readpipe)){
         fprintf(stdout, "%c", buf);
      }
   }


   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [tmpfile](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tmpfile)() is one way to do it.  However, I believe tmpfile() is frowned upon these days due to security concerns.

So, you should use [mkstemp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mkstemp) in POSIX or [tmpfile_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3dz6009(VS.80).aspx) in Windows instead of tmpfile().

These will all still create files in the filesystem, though.  They're temporary in that they "go away" when the program exits.

Another option, which doesn't create a physical file is [mmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap)().

Answer (score 0):

Oops, just found it... maybe.  tmpfile() returns a tmeporary FILE *

Is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Unix (or a similar OS), you want to read **Beej's Guide to Unix Interprocess Communication** (it's a good read no matter what your OS is).
Check it out at [Beej's Guides](http://beej.us/guide/).

In a rapid glance there I noticed a few things you could probably use with more or less work (and with the optional creation of a file/resource):

> - Pipes
> - FIFOs
> - Message Queues
> - Shared Memory Segments
> - Memory Mapped Files
> - Unix Sockets